# mailgun-php error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

I'm calling mailgun using mailgun-php to send a message through a PHP page on GoDaddy windows hosting. I just started over with a fresh install of the latest of mailgun-php by following the installation instructions. Now I'm getting this error message. The highest version of PHP I can have on GoDaddy windows hosting is 5.6. I've been searching for several hours, and have not been able to find an answer. Below the error message is my code.

> [15-Dec-2018 10:36:22 America/Phoenix] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught
> exception 'Http\Client\Exception\RequestException' with message 'error
> setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:
> c:\cgi\php56\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none' in
> D:\Hosting\redacted\mailgun-php\vendor\php-http\curl-client\src\Client.php:137
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\Hosting\redacted\mailgun-php\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(108):
>
> Http\Client\Curl\Client->sendRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
>
> ## 1 D:\Hosting\redacted\mailgun-php\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(179):
>
> Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->send('POST', '...', Array, Array)
>
> ## 2 D:\Hosting\redacted\mailgun-php\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(204):
>
> Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('..', Array, Array)
>
> ## 3 D:\Hosting\redacted\mailgun-php\sendmail.php(66): Mail in D:\Hosting\redacted\mailgun-php\vendor\php-http\curl-client\src\Client.php
>
> on line 137

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set ('log_errors', 'on');
ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 'on');
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log','D:\Hosting\redacted\html\phplogs\php_errors.log');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'POST')
    die('Invalid Mail Send request - rejected');

$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
$attachments = json_decode($_POST['attachments']);
$toName = htmlspecialchars($_POST['toName']);
$toAddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['toAddress']);
$emailTag = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email_tag']);
$from = "Site.com <quote@site.com>";
$domain = "<domain>";

error_log('>>>>>> ' . $emailTag);


// setup credentials
$mg = new Mailgun("key");

# Next, instantiate a Message Builder object from the SDK.
$msgBldr = $mg->MessageBuilder();
# Define the from address.
$msgBldr->setFromAddress($from);
# Define a to recipient.
$msgBldr->addToRecipient($toAddress);
#Define bcc for maintenance
$msgBldr->addBccRecipient('dev@dev.com');
# Define the subject.
$msgBldr->setSubject($subject);
# Define the body of the message.
$msgBldr->setTextBody($message);

$tempfiles = array();
# Add attachments
error_log("Attachment Count: " . strval(count($attachments)));
foreach ($attachments as $key => $value){

    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $value->name);
    file_put_contents($temp_file, base64_decode($value->content));
    $attSuccess = $msgBldr->addAttachment($temp_file, $value->name);
    $tempfiles[] = $temp_file;
}

$msg = $msgBldr->getMessage();
error_log("Message to send: " . json_encode($msg));

$files = $msgBldr->getFiles();
error_log("Sending files: " . json_encode($files));

$postAddr = "$domain/messages";
error_log("PostTo: " . $postAddr);

# Finally, send the message.
$mg->post($postAddr, $msg, $files);

// clean up temp files
foreach($tempfiles as $key => $f_name){
    unlink($f_name);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows sometimes you have a problem with curl when you don't have defined a valid and new CA-File.

https://superuser.com/questions/442793/why-cant-curl-properly-verify-a-certificate-on-windows

Here is an example how to download and define a ca file. I don't know if that solves your problem but you can try it. Perhaps then you get a valid connection.